# How to configure Apache Cordova with OData?

Tags: cordova, odata, webapi

I'll develop an application with Apache cordova but I don't know much about this. To start, I have to do this. **I will use OData** as the protocol. With the Apache cordova mobile application, I want to write data somewhere(sqlite, mongodb etc.) and print the data I wrote on the screen.

Is there any document or video I can use on this subject? Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Apache Cordova is just a tool to bundle web applications into native applications you wont need a special tutorial for Cordova. You can just follow instructions how to work with OData in general web applications.